# Cannot access DD-WRT after changing Router IP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have a fresh Linksys E2500 running DD-WRT K26 NV60 mega and everything works fine, but when I log into the Web GUI and change the Router IP address and subnet under the setup tab, everything breaks.

The default is set to 192.168.1.1/24, but I want to use 10.0.0.1/8.  So I change the IP address and the subnet mask to 10.0.0.1 and 255.0.0.0 respectivly and apply.

The page reloads, but then I can no longer navigate around so it is no longer using the 192.168.1.1 address like it should.  So I'll change my IP address in Windows to 10.0.0.2/8.

Nothing.  I can't ping, ssh/telnet, or get the GUI.  I tried restarting the router and the client with the same results.  Why does this happen?  Am I configuring something wrong or missing something?

Comment: Not quite sure why you set it to 255.0.0.0 for a home/soho network - even large networks with thousands of connections don't do this... The damage is done, however. You may need to reset the router but you might lose DD-WRT in the process and get the standard firmware back... At least 192.168.0.1 will work again for you to have another shot. Put DD-WRT back on, configure it without changing the router IP, backup settings, change IP again, test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an answer to your question. It looks like 10.0.0.1/8 is known to make some routers unresponsive. Try doing a 30/30/30 reset and using 10.0.0.1/24

http://lists.pfsense.org/pipermail/list/2011-November/000813.html

Comment: I'm selecting your answer as correct, and would like to give a shoutout to @Big-Chris whos comment was also helpful.